# How to store efficiently very large sparse 3D matrices

Tags: cnn, bigdata, data-formats

To train a CNN, I have stacked arrays of images over observations `[observations x width x length]`. The dataset is very sparse ($95\%$). What would be an efficient way of storing these matrices efficiently in terms of

- format (e.g. pickle, parquet)
- structure (e.g. `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`, List of Lists)

Comment: It is not clear what is sparse here? >65% does not look like sparse, or is there some typo? Also images are not typically sparse data.

Comment: Thanks, typo indeed as I was referring to above 95% sparsity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sparse matrix compression techniques is a massively efficient way of storing sparse data. Scipy package has a variety of methods to address the above in `scipy.sparse`. However, none of these are compatible with matrix dimensions higher than 2.

I have found handy the Sparse package that supports Coordinate List compression (COO), for higher dimension matrices, as in my use case:

Sparse matrix compression with coo

```py
#Load sequence array file
A = np.load('array.npy', allow_pickle=True)
sparsity = 1 - (np.count_nonzero(A) / A.size)
print( "Sparsity of A:%s%%" % np.round(sparsity,3))
Sparsity of A:0.996%

#Calculate coordinate list sparse array of A
S = sparse.COO(A)

# Size calculation.
print('Size of A in bytes: %s' %A.nbytes)
Size of A in bytes: 16563527400
print('Size of S in bytes: %s' %S.nbytes)
Size of S in bytes: 249330624
```

On disk:

```
array.npy --> 15.43 GB
array_after.npy  --> 16.40 MB
```